# How list/remove globally installed Dart dependencies?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I try to figure out how to manage pub packages. For example, I have the following **pubspec.yaml**:

```
name: app
dependencies:
  intl: any
  browser: any
  polymer: any
transformers:
  - polymer
```

After time I consider to remove `intl` package. As far as I understand running `pub get` again automatically remove unused packages (to be more precise it removes links but not actual files). If so how can I list/remove actual packages available globally (on Ubuntu under `/home/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only manually by deleting them using your OS tools. There is no `pub ...` support for that. 
`pub ...` only works for the current project (current working directory) and it doesn't know if versions are used by other projects on your disk.

Comment: Don't you think it's weird? What about unused dependencies? Keep in mind and delete manually? But the answer is simple: store ton of useless garbage again and again :D. Sometimes Dart developers really surprise me for the worse..

Comment: You can just delete the whole `.pub-cache` folder and run `pub get` or `pub upgrade` in the projects you work.

Comment: Remove dozens of packages and download them again because of one - you know that it ins't solution.

Comment: I don't worry much about it. Sometimes I just delete the `~/.pub-cache/hosted` directory and let it refill. How would `pub` be able to keep track which projects on your disk point to which version of a package? This are just a few hundred megs at most. If you use Windows and worry about such things you won't be able to sleep at night.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [den](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/den) tool. It's a community-contributed tool that provides various utilities for working with pub packages.

`den uninstall thing_i_do_not_need_anymore`

Comment: It really surprise that even @SethLadd offers the third-party tool. If to be honest it should be built in feature, eg something like `pub remove -g package` (or like in npm: `npm uninstall -g package`). It is about package management not about some really extraordinary functionality.

Comment: Because you don't install them in Dart there is no way to uninstall them. It's just a cache. `den` was built from a member from the Dart team anyway. I would not having this https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5499 find this a lot more bothersome.

Comment: There is no the only one truth anyway, only time will tell) As always, thank you Gunter)