# How to Uninstall Flutterfire CLI on Mac?

Tags: flutter, macos, firebase-tools

Lets say the flutterfire cli has been installed on a Mac using:

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

How do you uninstall it?

I tried the docs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How list/remove globally installed Dart dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705387/how-list-remove-globally-installed-dart-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

You used `activate` to install it, simply using `deactivate` will uninstall it;

```bash
dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli
```

Comment: I tried this and I still get the old accounts on the CLI. This simply deactivates the plugin but does not uninstall it.